# Power and Power Loss of a DC to AC converter (Motor Driver)

Tags: power, pwm, oscilloscope, dc-ac

I need urgent help on this matter and I really appreciate it if anyone can clear my doubts!

I have a motor driver evaluation board, namely NXP's [FRDM-HB2001-EVM](http://www.nxp.com/assets/documents/data/en/user-guides/KTFRDMHB2001EVMUG.pdf), which functions as a simple DC to AC converter based on the PWM input it receives. I am interested in the efficiency of this device but I need some help in properly calculating the input and output power because because PWM is involved.

My setup is as follows:

- A PWM signal generated by an Arduino UNO is input into the evaluation board, FRDM-HB2001-EVM.
- Input voltage of 7.2V is supplied into the FRDM-HB2001-EVM, and then input current, output voltage and output current are measure using a voltage probe and a current clamp with an oscilloscope.
- The input voltage is a constant DC voltage, but the input current, output voltage and output current are 'AC' due to the effect of the PWM input, which makes the HB2001 function as a half bridge.

I would like to ask, what is the best method to accurately calculate the input power, output power, and the efficiency just by the values obtained through the oscilloscope?

Comment: Since you have an oscilloscope, you can measure the peak values of both input and output currents then simply get mean values by \$I_{mean} = I_{pk} \cdot D\$, where D is duty cycle which can be measured easily via oscilloscope. If supply voltage for motor (i.e. output voltage) is generated by the board itself then you can roughly calculate the efficiency from \$(V_{out} \cdot I_{M-Load}) / (V_{in} \cdot I_{M-input})\$.

Answer (score 0):

For accurate results, instantaneous values of current X voltage must be calculated at the input and output over one or more cycles of the output waveform. The sample interval is determined by the PWM frequency. The number of output cycles over which data must be collected is determined by examining the variation from one cycle to the next.

Comment: Hi Charles, thank you so much for your swift reply. Is it good enough for me to observe the instantaneous RMS power of the my voltage waveform * current waveform for both my inputs and outputs to do the comparison of the efficiency of my device?

Comment: RMS current and RMS voltage are a convenient means of calculating power, but the resulting power is not an RMS value. With a sufficient sampling rate and accurate current and voltage measurement, the method that I described can be sufficiently accurate for efficiently comparison.